# c++: the possibility of using std::pair in switch

Tags: c++, c++11

I wrote example. I want to use the std::pair in switch condition, but compiler says me that:

0) ‘t’ used in its own initializer;

1) "the value of ‘t’ is not usable in a constant expression"

Is it possible to make something like this or is it stupid and I need to go read the standard.
Best regards.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

bool Task() {
    std::cout<<"Hello Stack!" <<std::endl;
}


template<typename T>
void check_case(const uint8_t key, T val) {
    constexpr auto t =  std::pair<std::function<bool()>, uint8_t>([=] { return Task(); }, 0);
    switch (val) {
        case 0: {
            std::cout << "val are uint8" << std::endl;
        }break;
        case t: {
            std::cout << "val are pair" << std::endl;
        }break;
    }
}


int main() {
    uint8_t key = 0;
    uint8_t val = 0;
    check_case(key, val);

    auto t =  std::pair<std::function<bool()>, uint8_t>([=] { return Task(); }, 0);
    check_case(key, t);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Case labels must be constants, so no, it's not possible.

Comment: And to get rid of the second error, drop `constexpr`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I thought constexpr will cope. ty

Comment: Even if you could use pairs in a switch, all of `check_case` must be correctly typed regardless of which type `T` it is instantiated with.

Comment: @molbdnilo I understood. Using the auto type in template - bad way. ty

Comment: You can probably make this example work in C++17 by replacing the switch statement with an `if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<T>) { ... } else { ...}` but I'm not sure if you should... Can you give us a hint what problem you are actually trying to solve?

Comment: @Tobi ty I'll try this. I have to add some tasks depending on the configuration. For example, for val == 0 I need to add task0 (I have std :: map <uint16_t, std :: pair <std :: function <bool ()>, uint8_t >> for tasks), for val == 1 - task1, and so on. These are the required tasks. And if some special variable occurs in the configuration, I need to run a special task. I could use some numeric constant for such cases, but I wanted to pass std :: pair <std :: function <bool ()>, uint8_t>

Comment: @Max: Have a look at std::variant and std::visit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch condition can be either integral or enumeration type. Passing class as switch condition requires it to be convertible either of them.

> 9.4.2 The switch statement [stmt.switch]
>
> 2 The condition shall be of integral type, enumeration type, or class type. If of class type, the condition is contextually implicitly converted (Clause 7) to an integral or enumeration type. If the (possibly converted) type is subject to integral promotions (7.6), the condition is converted to the promoted type. Any statement within the switch statement can be labeled with one or more case labels as follows:
>
> *case constant-expression :*
>
> where the constant-expression shall be a converted constant expression (8.20) of the adjusted type of the
>   switch condition.

If you are going to use class as switch value it needs to be constexpr-convertable to corresponding integral or enumerator type:

```
class Foo
{
    public: int m_v{};

    public: constexpr
    operator int(void) const
    {
        return m_v;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo x{};
    switch(x)
    {
       case Foo{1}: break;
       case Foo{2}: break;
    }
}
```

Since `std::pair` does not fit into these requirements it can not be used as a switch (or case) condition. But the actual problem with this code is that the value `t` supplied to `case` is not a constexpr. To achieve dynamic switch / case -like behavior you will need to use some other means, for example mapping values.

Comment: Does this mean that you could (with the right sprinkling of constexpr magic) use hash values as your cases? Just a thought. For small pair types hashes may be fully mapped.

Comment: @GemTaylor Yes, it is possible.